# Overloaded function differ only by return type

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to make a program that detects where two linked list intersect.

```
class LinkedList 
{
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            int value;
            Node *next;
            Node(int v,Node *n);
            Node(int v);
        };
        Node *head;
        int list_size; 

        public:
            virtual int size();
            virtual bool isEmpty();

            virtual int findLength();

            virtual LinkedList *findIntersection( Node *head, Node *head2);
        // Other linked list methods. 
};

LinkedList:: Node:: Node(int v,Node *n)
{
    value = v;
    next = n; 
}

LinkedList:: Node:: Node(int v) 
{
    value = v;
    next = nullptr; 
}

LinkedList:: Node *LinkedList:: findIntersection( Node *head, Node *head2) 
{
    int l1 = 0;
    int l2 = 0;
    Node *tempHead = head;
    Node *tempHead2 = head2;
    while (tempHead != nullptr)
    {
        l1++;
        tempHead = tempHead-> next;
    }
    while (tempHead2 != nullptr)
    {
        l2++;
        tempHead2 = tempHead2-> next;
    }
    int diff;
    if (l1 < 12)
    {
        Node *temp = head;
        head = head2;
        head2 = temp;
        diff = l2 - l1;
    }
    else
    {
        diff = l1 - l2;
    }
    for (; diff > 0; diff--)
    {
        head = head-> next;
    }
    while (head != head2)
    {
        head = head-> next;
        head2 = head2-> next;
    }
    return head; 
}
```

**I am calling the above function in main() as follows:**

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList* ll = new LinkedList();  LinkedList* l2, l3;
    l3 = ll->findIntersection( ll, l2);
    cout<<"\nIntersection point is: ";  l3 -> print();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error C2556: 'LinkedList::Node *LinkedList::findIntersection(LinkedList::Node *,LinkedList::Node *)':
  overloaded function differs only by return type from 
  'LinkedList *LinkedList::findIntersection(LinkedList::Node *,LinkedList::Node *)'
error C2371: 'LinkedList::findIntersection': redefinition; different basic types
```

How can I remove this error?

Comment: They have to be different in signature

Comment: For the declaration `LinkedList* l2, l3;` only `l2` is a pointer.

Comment: So use `LinkedList *l2, *l3;`. Note the whitespace.

Comment: **The compiler tells you exactly the problem in a clear message.** You simply have to read it. It is very obvious that in one case you have declared the function to returns a `Linked List *`and the next time you have used `Node *`.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge Whitespace might improve readability, but it has no effect on parsing of that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your declaration of the `findIntersection` function differs from the definition.

The declaration is

```
virtual LinkedList *findIntersection( Node *head, Node *head2);
```

The definition is

```
LinkedList:: Node *LinkedList:: findIntersection( Node *head, Node *head2)
```

As you can easily see when comparing them like this, the return-type is different. One of them have to be a typo.

Comment: I think declaration is incorrect. What is the correct way to declare it then?

Comment: @AdityaGupta To have both the declaration and definition have the same return type. Which is correct is irrelevant really, the problem is that they are different.

Comment: I would say you according to return type `virtual Node *findIntersection( Node *head, Node *head2);`

Comment: Now I am getting this error after modifying the code as you suggested:
 error C2664: 'LinkedList::Node *LinkedList::findIntersection(LinkedList::Node *,LinkedList::Node *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'LinkedList *' to 'LinkedList::Node *'
error C2819: type 'LinkedList' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'